# No library found under: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.9.0

Tags: cuda, nvidia-jetson, jax

I'm trying to install JAX on the NVIDIA Jetson TX2 and I'm facing considerable issues.

I have CUDA 9.0 and it gives me the following error:

```
No library found under: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcublasLt.so.9.0
```

So I go looking and of course that library does not exist. Does anyone have any pointers on how I can about installing that library? I've tried searching google and it does not appear to exist at all.

Comment: There is no libcublasLt for CUDA 9.0.  It did not come into existence until CUDA 10.1.  The proper way to get CUDA libraries like this on a jetson is to install the latest JetPack.

Comment: That would explain so much. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cublasLt library did not come into existence until cuda 10.1  [here is the cublas 10.0 doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cublas/index.html) and [here is the cublas 10.1 doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/cublas/index.html).

Therefore you won't be able to use cublasLt with CUDA 9.0

On a Jetson the correct way to get the latest CUDA install including libraries like cublas is to install the latest JetPack.